# Chicago Traffic-Related Fatalities

Tags: data-request, usa, transportation, medical

Where can I find Chicago traffic-related fatalities by day (and also ideally time)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This data used to be publicly available through the Illinois Department of Transportation's Safety Data Mart. However, the Department's new [Safety Portal](https://webapps.dot.illinois.gov/SafetyPortal/) is [now only accessible to other government agencies](http://chi.streetsblog.org/2015/08/21/state-transportation-department-is-refusing-to-provide-crash-data-to-citizens/).

For Chicago data, you can get historical data from the [Chicago Crash Browser](https://github.com/stevevance/Chicago-Crash-Browser/blob/master/DATA.md)

Comment: Link does not work anymore. Here is an updated one https://data.cityofchicago.org/browse?tags=traffic taken from https://github.com/graphhopper/open-traffic-collection#usa

Comment: Those links don't got to any crash data, as far as I can see.

Comment: my bad...should have looked closer. apologies